# Is this a good way to determine the maximum size of a type in a hierarchy?

Tags: c++

I need to reserve space to handle types up to a certain size in some `std::aligned_storage<>`. Is the following a safe and correct way of determining the maximum size of my storage?

```
template <std::size_t size> // need to handle types with a maximum size of 'size'
class storage
{
    class holder_base
    {
        virtual ~holder_base() = default;
    };

    // will only ever hold 'data' as a data member
    // static_assert will ensure sizeof(T) <= size
    template <typename T>
    class holder : public holder_base
    {
        T data;
    };

    // used to determine maximum size, including any added size from inheritance
    class holder_size_t : public storage_base 
    {
        char filler[ size ];
    };

    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof( holder_size_t )> memory;
};
```

Is `memory` guaranteed to be able to hold any `holder<T>` and also guaranteed to be properly accessible through a cast such as `reinterpret_cast<holder_base*>(&memory)` without undefined behaviour?

Comment: You have "typo": `holder_base::~storage_base`.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for pointing that out.